# Video.js Simple function Failing

Tags: javascript, video, video.js

This seems like it should be  a super simple function, but some reason currentFrame(canv2); returns 'undefined'

I have many more complex functions using all the same elements as this, and they all work.

```
var frameRate = 30;

var players=new Array(_V_("video_canvas_1"), _V_("video_canvas_2"));

var canv1 = players[0];
var canv2 = players[1];

function currentFrame(e) {
    frameRate * e.currentTime();
}
```

**Update**
So I wrote the value to the console, and of course it works great:

```
function currentFrame(e) {
    frameRate * e.currentTime();
    console.log('currentTime * frameRate:' + frameRate * e.currentTime());
}
```

returns

```
currentTime * frameRate:102.09498167037964 main.js:45
currentTime * frameRate:102.09498167037964 main.js:45
currentTime * frameRate:102.09498167037964 main.js:45
```

Comment: why is `currentFrame()` not returning a value?

Comment: missing a return statement? or * should be *= for assignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you may need

```
function currentFrame(e) {
    return frameRate * e.currentTime();
}
```